# Cannot use android:Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I've ready pretty much every question on here, answered or no, and followed all of the steps, to no avail. I am using Eclipse to use Google App Engine. This is what I've done:

-Added android-support-v4.jar to my libs folder
-Added android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to my libs folder
-Right click project >> Properties >> Libraries tab; Click "Add JARs..." >> browse to libs folder and select those two JARs
-Select "Order and Export" tab; checked both of those JARs; unchecked "Android Dependencies"; Click "OK"

This is my styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.appengine"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<permission
    android:name="com.appengine.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.appengine.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.appengine" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.appengine" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SendData"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:value="android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity" />
</application>
```

When I attempt to run the project (USB connected Galaxy S4, currently running 4.4.2) I get:

```
G:\workspace\appengine\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

I've been fighting this for a few days now, can anyone save me from giving up the life of a developer?

Comment: Well don't give up developing. If you really want to save a developer's life then you should stop using Eclipse and start using Android Studio. Google has dropped support for Eclipse long ago and what took many steps to download and reference appcompat.v7 in Eclipse is just a single line in AS

Answer (score 3):

I have never referenced any theme with `android` namespace.

Usually it's

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

or just:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't just add the v7 jar to your libs folder.  you need to make a library project for v7 and link your project to that.

read the section 'Adding libraries with resources' on https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

PS, but the v4 jar can simply be dropped in the libs folder.

Comment: When I right click the jar, all I get is "Configure Build Path...". That's part of the reason I have been fighting it so much, the instructions aren't matching what I have. I'm using Eclipse Luna, if that affects anything.

Comment: don't right click the jar, remove the jar.   then make sure you are reading the section 'Adding libraries WITH resources'.  these instructions don't make it clear, but what you will end up with is two projects in your workspace instead of one.  one of these will be 'android-support-v7-appcompat' and the other is 'your-app'.  PS I also use Eclipse Luna.